# Could not get unknown. Property 'flutter' for extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle

- error : FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\flutter\mhm\android\app\build.gradle' line: 30
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not get unknown property 'flutter' for extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- > ```
  > line 30 : android {
  >     namespace "com.example.mhm"
  >     compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
  >     ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion
  > ```
- flutter doctor: no issues found !

Comment: I also tried flutter clean then upgrade .. didn't work.

Comment: What is your question? What are you trying to do? Which commands did you use to do it? Also, please format your text correctly.